# MFPPush.registerDevice wrapped by obtainAccessToken failed

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying to run MFP8's push [sample app](https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/PushNotificationsCordova/blob/release80/www/js/index.js) of GitHub. But MFPPush.registerDevice method failed and error message "Failed to register device:" was shown.

```
function registerDevice() {
  WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken("push.mobileclient").then(
    MFPPush.registerDevice(
      null,
      function(successResponse) {
        navigator.notification.alert("Successfully registered");
        enableButtons();    
      }, 
      function(failureResponse) {
        navigator.notification.alert("Failed to register");
        console.log("Failed to register device:" + 
                    JSON.stringify(failureResponse));
      }
    )
  );
}
```

I read the [MFP8 document](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/notifications/handling-push-notifications/cordova/) and found the note below.

> Note: Authenticated notifications are currently not supported in Cordova applications due to a defect. However a workaround is provided: each MFPPush API call can be wrapped by WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken("push.mobileclient").then( ... );. The provided sample application uses this workround.

The sample code is wrapped by WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken indeed. But I think MFPPush.registerDevice may be called before 'obtainAccessToken' completes because return value of MFPPush.registerDevice's method is specified as Promise.then() parameter instead of function that call MFPPush.registerDevice.

So I think the sample should be written as bellow,

```
function registerDevice() {
  WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken("push.mobileclient").then(
    function() {
      MFPPush.registerDevice(
        null,
        function(successResponse) {
          navigator.notification.alert("Successfully registered");
          enableButtons();    
        }, 
        function(failureResponse) {
          navigator.notification.alert("Failed to register");
          console.log("Failed to register device:" + 
                      JSON.stringify(failureResponse));
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Could anyone give me some advice about that?

There is additional information. In device log these messages were logged.
Of course, I registered UserLogin security check to MobileFirst Server and UserLogin challengeHandler is created in [UserLoginChallengeHandler.js](https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/PushNotificationsCordova/blob/release80/www/js/UserLoginChallengeHandler.js)
(I have not changed except bundleId)

2018-02-10 19:42:47.271015+0900 PushNotificationsCordova[1273:1500711] Failed to register device:"Error Domain=com.ibm.mfp.push Code=5 \"Error authenticating client. Error is 'Challenge handler does not exist. There is no registered challenge handler with key UserLogin'.\" UserInfo={networkMetadata={\n    \"$bytesSent\" = 120;\n    \"$category\" = network;\n    \"$outboundTimestamp\" = 1518259366869;\n    \"$path\" = \"http://192.168.0.105:9080/mfp/api/preauth/v1/preauthorize\";\n    \"$requestMethod\" = POST;\n    \"$trackingid\" = \"F8FD4A96-B046-4DAD-87F6-7441E8426C2E\";\n}, NSLocalizedDescription=Error authenticating client. Error is 'Challenge handler does not exist. There is no registered challenge handler with key UserLogin'.}"

Comment: What is the output of this line - "console.log("Failed to register device:" + 
                JSON.stringify(failureResponse));" , in device logs?

Comment: Here is my environment.

Environment:  
MFP:8.0.0.00-20180130-110339  
node version=v6.12.3  
npm version=3.10.10  
cordova version=7.1.0

Comment: In your application registrataion's security tab, have you mapped your push.mobileclient scope to a security check? If so, did you deploy the "UserLogin" security check adapter?

Comment: Yes, I added push.mobileclient scope to Sample App and assigned UserLogin security check. Of course deployed 'UserLogin' adapter.

Comment: The sample has been corrected. Do you continue to get this error message?

Comment: Thank you for your information. I have update the sample and confirmed the sample worked correctly.

Comment: Please add your suggestion about the promise as the answer, so that others will benefit